# How to get data from an async function in React

Tags: reactjs, function, async-await

I am using react-adal to authenticate to Azure AD. By using runWithAdal function as a wrapper for my app, it works like a charm.

[image]

authContext is the AuthenticationContext containing IDs utilized in making the OIDC call. When I hardcode those, everything works like a charm. Of course, we don't want to hard code so those IDs are stored in a config.json file. I have an async function that "loads" those IDs from the file and returns them.

[image]

The problem is that I have to use an async function with await when calling this load function. As you can see below those IDs used to build the adalConfig component. My question is how do I do all of this under an async function. I have tried creating variables and setting the value of those variables within the async function, but when I do a console.log() of one of the variables outside of the function I get "Undefined" ???? Does anyone have any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: I don't need for anything to happen before I get the config. I can do a console.log() "within" the function and I will see the value. If I do it "outside" of the function, I get nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to call first the load function using `load().then(response => {`
Then you use the response to build the `adalConfig` and call `runWithAdal` from inside that.
Here's an example:

```
load().then(response => {
   const authContext = buildAuthContext(response);

   runWithAdal(authContext,() => {
     ReactDOM.render(<Router> <App /> </Router>, 
        document.getElementById("root"));
     }, DO_NOT_LOGIN);
   },DO_NOT_LOGIN);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. To improve quality even more, consider editing to include *why* your suggest this solution. Most upvotes are accrued over time as future visitors learn something to help with (or prevent) their own coding issues. Great job highlighting your process with text as an intro to the code! Looking forward to more contributions from you.